# open link in specific browser(like IE) instead of default browser from react-native app?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-linking, react-native-windows

I'm creating app which need to be opens in Microsoft edge browser but when i click on link. it is directly opening link with default browser. Is there a way to force the program to open the link in Microsoft edge browser instead of the default browser. Especially in IOS.

```
 openUrl = (url) => {
    Linking.openURL(url)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

On iOS-

Try opening your link with following in js file.

```
Linking.openURL('microsoft-edge-https://www.google.com');
```

And in your PList file add

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
      <string>microsoft-edge-https</string>
  </array>
```